# Make the tag frequency number clearer

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags-page

The new tag page displays the frequency at which a question with the tag is asked. for example, 28 questions with the discussion tag have been asked 123 this week. However, that isn't very clear. It took me a while before getting what "28 today, 123 week" or "[11 week, 27 month](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tags)."

It's particularly bad in very low frequency tags which can read "5 year." Very confusing, IMO.

I propose that a bit of text is added to make this clearer. There is enough space for it, anyway. For example, "28 today, 123 week" would not read "28 asked today, 123 this week" and "5 asked this year."

Comment: +1, a bit wordy, but a lot clearer than the "5 year" version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, we'll try this, but I am concerned it might be a bit wordy.

I do like the word "asked" being on the page as it emphasizes "hey, these are tags I can put on *questions I ask*", which is an important cue for new users.